# Shortest path passing though some defined nodes

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

In a directed graph, find the shortest path from s to t such that the path passes through a certain subset of V, let's call them death nodes. The algorithm is given a number n, while traversing from s to t, the path cannot pass though more than n death nodes. What is the best way to find the shortest path, her? I am thiniing Dijkstra's, but how to make sure we are not passing though more than n nodes? Please help me tweak Dijkstra's to include this condition.

Answer (score 1):

### Small n

If n is small you can make n copies of your graph, call them levels 1 to n.

You start at s in level 1.  If you are at a normal node, the edges take you to nodes within the same level.  If you are at a death node, the edges take you to nodes within the next level.  If you are at a death node on level n, the edges are simply omitted.

Also connect the t nodes at all levels to a new single destination T (with zero weight).

Then compute the shortest path from s to T.

The problem with this approach is that the graph size goes up by a factor of n, so it is only appropriate for small n.

### Large n

An alternative approach is to increase the weight for each edge leaving a death node by a variable x.

As you increase the variable x, the shortest path will use fewer and fewer death nodes.  Adjust the value for x (e.g. with bisection) until the graph only uses n  death nodes.

This should take around O(logn) evaluations of the shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add the number of dead nodes encountered on the way as a new (sparse) dimension to the computed distance -- basically you'd have up to n best distances per node.

Implementing your own BFS would be similar: You'll need to treat "seen with x dead nodes" different from "seen with y dead nodes" for each node, unless the total distance and number of dead nodes on the way are both smaller.

**p.s.**: If you get stuck with this approach, please post code so far O:)